# Is there a quicker method to get and output all filenames in a directory tree?

Tags: batch-file, for-loop

```
For /r %%a in (*.mp4) do (
echo %%~nxa >> FilenameList.txt
)

sort FilenameList.txt > FilenameList_sorted.txt
```

The above will output only filenames with their extensions (mp4 files) from the directory, and sub-directories included, from where the script is ran. The next part will sort the completed file by sorting each line alphabetically and outputting that to a new file. But the loop is very slow.
Two questions

1. How can this script run faster by perhaps changing the methodology in
   which this works?
2. Can the (*.mp4) part be changed to an array so that multiple
   specific file types can be listed in the output instead if just one file type; if so, how?

Thank you

Comment: You could `dir /s *.mp4` with some other tweaks.

Comment: For the multiple file type extension, `dir` supports multiple file extensions. Example: `dir /s *.mp4 *.avi`

Comment: I have no idea why everyone thinks `dir /s` is the solution, it's like it's a 10 year long running troll. Just stop please. `dir /s` is not a solution, `Dir /s` will always output file's WITH their paths when `/s` is used. Do it, have a directory with sub-directories all with files and do `dir /s` or `dir /s /b /o:n /a-d >> test.txt` and you'll see for yourself. `/a-d` won't change `/s` behavior.

Comment: Sir, I'm trying to fix this `/s` issue now. I know the `/s` creates incorrect result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code

```
For /r %%a in (*.mp4) do (
echo %%~nxa >> FilenameList.txt
)
```

is generally the same the following code. However, the former one outputs each new file one by one, while the latter one outputs all the file at once. The difference is significant when processing large amount of files.

```
for /r %%a in (*.mp4) do (
    echo %%~nxa
) >> FilenameList.txt
```

---

I also noticed that in the `()` clause, multiple file extension can be used.

```
for /r %%a in (*.mp4 *.avi) do (
    echo %%~nxa
) >> FilenameList.txt
```

Comment: Thanks but the whole point of using the FOR loop as in my OP is to avoid getting full paths but just the filenames + extensions by use of `%%~nx$`

Comment: @LevyImage Fixed, please check

Comment: Hi Steve, I tried your suggestion, speed is about the same when moving the append outside the parenthesis. I've seen faster unrelated results before with other scripts but I can't find them atm for reference. Perhaps if all files were parsed an put into a... variable or array?.. and then output to the text file?

Comment: @LevyImage Outputting the result to a variable, and then `echo` the variable to a file is much slower. Welp, the speed may not change much, but it's just an suggestion :)

Comment: Thanks Steve, I'll keep the append outside the parenthesis.

Comment: @Levy I'm not very sure if the "append" statement's location would affect the speed, but logically, putting `>>` outside the parenthesis *ought to* be faster.

Comment: yes, it *is* faster - much faster. With a lot of data it might even be a factor of >100. The problem here is: it's not the *writing*  that slows you down, but *scanning the disk*  (reading the filenames). Only way to make that faster is a SSD...